# Can I select multiple columns depending on a SELECT CASE?

Tags: sql, sybase

Based on the SELECT CASE below I want to show **two** separate columns within one WHEN. Is this possible?

The two commented out lines below are something like what I would like to have. I am sure it is something very simple I am missing. As it is, there is a syntax error.

```
select 
    person.FirstName,
    person.LastName,
    CASE 
        --WHEN substatus is not null then 'HasSubstatus', null
        --else null, 'DoesNotHaveSubstatus'
        WHEN substatus is not null then 'HasSubstatus'
        else null
    end
from Person person
```

Comment: Why have you tagged both mysql and sybase?

Comment: I removed the mysql tag, sry about that.

Comment: Is there a reason that you really need two columns, which both communicate the same exact data? Maybe your reporting engine has strange requirements or whatever, but it's one of those things that would raise a red flag with me to start.

Comment: @Tom H: I agree as well it seems strange for this requirement for the example provided in the question. But it was much simplified than to what I actually need it for (data conversion) and I wasn't sure if Select Case multiple columns was possible - and now I know based on Thomas answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it in a single Case expressions as a Case expression returns a single value. You must use two Case expressions.

```
Select  person.FirstName
    , person.LastName
    , Case When substatus is not null Then 'HasSubstatus' End As [HasSubstatus]
    , Case When substatus is null Then 'DoesNotHaveSubstatus' End As [DoesNotHaveSubstatus]
From Person person
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You would need to repeat the case statement if you mean that you want to apply the same conditional logic to 2 columns or have it as a separate query if you mean that in one case it should return two columns and in the other case one column.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with `if()` and `isnull()` (*this syntax would work only in mySql*)

```
select 
    person.FirstName,
    person.LastName,
    IF( ISNULL(substatus),'HasSubstatus', null ) AS DoesHave,
    IF( ISNULL(substatus),null,'DoesNotHaveSubstatus'  ) AS DoesNotHave,
from Person person
```

Comment: -1 Syntax error: wrong number of parameters to function 'ISNULL'

Comment: @VoodooChild, sorry was using the mysql syntax..  @thomas answer is the way to go ..

Comment: oh I didn't know that this would work in mysql. I tried removing the downvote but it says vote is locked unless answer is edited.

Comment: @VoodooChild, no worries.. (*although i did just added a disclaimer that it is only for mySql*)